# how can I set a goal on recommendation system ?(mean average precision, baselineRmse)

Tags: recommendation-engine, evaluation, precision-recall

I starting to develop offline recommendation system using [ALS algorithm](https://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-04-19/alternating-least-squares-method-for-collaborative-filtering/).
and I need to set a goal about system.

so I wanna know what criteria used to evaluate recommendation system.
I already know *MAP* (mean average precision) and improvement to *baselineRmse* and I would like to know: how is the performance on these criterions in modern recommendation systems to set my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the early days of recommenders people thought predicting ratings was a good idea. This has since proven to be nearly useless of itself. If you have enough space in a UI to show a few recommendations are you going to pick the one you think the user will pick with the highest ratings? That will always result in bad performance. Rating prediction is what RMSE was designed to measure.

MAP@k on the other hand is meant to find the predictiveness in a recommender. It measures how well the training data predicts what is in the test data. It also accounts for the ordering of recommendations. Ranking/ordering of recommendations has more recently been discovered to have a much greater effect on the effectiveness of recommendations because if you can only show a limited number they had better be the most likely to cause a user to take action.

MAP@k also takes account of ranking in the sense that if you measure MAP@1 and MAP@10, you will see decreasing MAP scores **if** your first recommendation was more likely to be in the test data than the 10th. This means you are ordering recommendations roughly correct.

For these reason we use MAP@k. Split the "gold standard" dataset you will use in later rests and keep the split static—something like 80%-20% will work split by random choice or by time, the most recent 20% used as the test split. Build you model on the 80%, then for each interaction in the 20% get recommendations and see if the recommendations contain the item actually interacted with in the test set. The aggregate of all these will go into the MAP@k calculation, k is based on how many recommendation you ask for.

See these references and some tools we have to do this:

- Kaggle blog  references python code they and we [ActionML](http://actionml.com) use. https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/MeanAveragePrecision
- [ActionML](http://actionml.com) analysis python code  to split data sets and run MAP@k, where we use the Kaggle function. https://github.com/actionml/analysis-tools